How to Load a Specific File from a Particular Snapshot/Baseline in RTC CLI using lscm load Command?
I'm trying to use the RTC CLI's lscm load command to fetch a specific file from a particular Snapshot/Baseline in Rational Team Concert (RTC). The command I've tried so far is:
lscm load -r <RTC_Server_URL> -u <Username> -P <Password> -d <Local_Directory> <workspace> <component><File_Path>

However, this command only seems to download the latest version of the file. I need to be able to download older versions of the file, similar to how we can use git checkout  in Git.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to achieve this in RTC CLI?
